# Magnetization work, $\delta W=BdM$

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, work, magnetic-moment

the coupling energy, between a magnetic dipole, and a magnetic field, is: $\epsilon=-\mu B$. Defining the magnetization of system made by $N$ dipoles as: $M=N \langle \mu \rangle$, the coupling energy between this system and the magnetic field is: $E=-MB$.
Writing the differential, taking B constant, $dE=-BdM$. Finally, since $dE=\delta W$, we get $\delta W = -BdM$.

Unfortunately, this formula is incorrect, the correct one is $\delta W=BdM$, why?

The convention is, work positive when entering in the system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the interaction energy of a dipole and a magnetic field \*negative\* when they are parallel?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240313/why-is-the-interaction-energy-of-a-dipole-and-a-magnetic-field-negative-when-t)

Comment: In particular, the pointer to the article by [Arsenović, D. & Božić](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.19481) ("*[Why is it that when] you
integrate the energy density..., you get (for the interaction term)...the ‘wrong’ sign.’*’)

Comment: no, i'm fine with negative coupling energy, is the resulting work that i don't understand

Comment: I find it hard to believe you read that article thoughtfully and thoroughly in one minute, but I'll take you at your word and retract my close vote.

Comment: sorry, i didn't read it, i've seen the title "Why is the Hamiltonian of a magnetic dipole −m⋅B", and, since my question is not about the form of hamiltonian, i thought it was not useful. If you think that it could be useful to solve by doubt i'll read it

Comment: i'd like to understand why, if $E=-MB$, so $dE=-BdM$, then, $dE=\delta W=-BdM$ is wrong (with the convention that work is positive when entering the system)

Comment: see chapter 11 in https://archive.org/details/fundamentalsofst00reif/page/439/mode/2up?view=theater

Comment: Right, whether the dipole or the dipole + field is considered in the system definition. See also [The sign makes a difference!](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.19064?journalCode=ajp)

Comment: i can't access this document